# Valid JSON breaks HandlebarsJS and $.getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, mustache

**Given html with an anchor and an handlebars/mustache's template:**

```
<!-- 1. Anchor -->
<div id="anchor">Anchor</div>

<!-- 2. HTML-Mustache template -->
<script id="ẗpl" type="text/template">
    {{#people}}
       <li><b>{{family}} {{name}}</b> ({{title}}, {{place}}) : {{introduction}}.</li>
    {{/people}}
</script>
```

**Given a data.json** (proven valid & from an 3rd party website):

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Hugo",
            "title": "leader",
            "place": "Paris",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, Gdal & D3js enthusiast, Cartographic workshop's dinosaure & rennovator"
        },
        {
            "family": "Ganesh",
            "name": "Arun",
            "title": "co-leader",
            "place": "Dharamsala",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, D3js enthusiast, interactions designers & wikidata tinker"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Given a JS handlebars.js call such :**

```
var url = '//bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/raw/8075193/data.json?callback=?'; // get loaded successfully
// Action below fails:
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var template = $('#tpl').html();
    var stone = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
    $('#anchor').append(stone);
});
```

**Why do I get and error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` ?**

How to make it works ?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGwJ9/9/

---

**Edit:** When I restructure my JSON as

```
{
  "people"
  :
     [ 
       ... 
     ]
}
```

the error message point to the 3rd line with the `":"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it, and the problem is that `//bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/raw/8075193/data.json?callback=callbackName` is sending back JSON, not a valid JSONP callback. Because of the `callback=?` in your URL, jQuery will be expecting JSONP, not JSON. JSON != JSONP. [JSON](http://json.org) is a textual data notation. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is a means of delivering JSON cross-domain using `script` tags. (Examples below.)

If you control what that URL returns, you can change it so that it wrap the JSON in the appropriate JSONP wrapper (basically putting the JSON inside a function call, where the name of the function comes from the `callback` parameter in the URL).

If you don't control what the URL returns, then unless that server supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and it allows your origin *and* you're using a [CORS-enabled browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), you won't be able to load that data cross-domain because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

Here's what that URL is sending back:

```
{ "people": [
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Hugo",
            "title": "leader",
            "place": "Paris",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, Gdal & D3js enthusiast, Cartographic workshop's dinosaure & rennovator",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Lopez_Hugo_Yug.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Hugo_lz"
        },
        {
            "family": "Ganesh",
            "name": "Arun",
            "title": "co-leader",
            "place": "Dharamsala",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, D3js enthusiast, interactions designers & wikidata tinker",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Ganesh_Arun_Planemad.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Edouard_lopez"
        },
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Edouard",
            "title": "support",
            "place": "Bordeaux",
            "introduction": "Backend admin & Frontend professional webdev, scripts & stack consulting",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Lopez_Edouard_Lyhana8.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Plandemad"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a valid JSONP response:

```
callbackName({ "people": [
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Hugo",
            "title": "leader",
            "place": "Paris",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, Gdal & D3js enthusiast, Cartographic workshop's dinosaure & rennovator",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Lopez_Hugo_Yug.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Hugo_lz"
        },
        {
            "family": "Ganesh",
            "name": "Arun",
            "title": "co-leader",
            "place": "Dharamsala",
            "introduction": "GIS cartographer, D3js enthusiast, interactions designers & wikidata tinker",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Ganesh_Arun_Planemad.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Edouard_lopez"
        },
        {
            "family": "Lopez",
            "name": "Edouard",
            "title": "support",
            "place": "Bordeaux",
            "introduction": "Backend admin & Frontend professional webdev, scripts & stack consulting",
            "photo": "img/WikiAtlas_Lopez_Edouard_Lyhana8.jpg",
            "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Plandemad"
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: json object != json object ?? I was not aware of that.

Comment: Remove the `?callback=?` get back to another fails : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/raw/8075193/data.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @Hugolpz: Right, because of the SOP. I guessed you might run into that and updated the answer. :-)